# Reading from an xml file

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have an xml file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<LogOnUsersInfo>
  <GeneralInformation>
    <NumberOfUsers>2</NumberOfUsers>
    <LastUser UserName="User1"/>
  </GeneralInformation>
  <LogOnUserCollection>
    <LogOnUser UserName="User1" Password="password">
      <Rights>
        <CanCreateProducts value="true"/>
        <CanEditProducts value="true"/>
        <CanDeleteProducts value="true"/>
        <CanCreateLogIns value="true"/>
        <CanDeleteLogIns value="true"/>
        <CanBeDeleted value="true"/>
        <HasDebugRights value="false"/>
      </Rights>
    </LogOnUser>  
    <LogOnUser UserName="User2" Password="password">
      <Rights>
        <CanCreateProducts value="true"/>
        <CanEditProducts value="true"/>
        <CanDeleteProducts value="true"/>
        <CanCreateLogIns value="true"/>
        <CanDeleteLogIns value="true"/>
        <CanBeDeleted value="true"/>
        <HasDebugRights value="false"/>
      </Rights>
    </LogOnUser>
  </LogOnUserCollection>
</LogOnUsersInfo>
```

And I have a class with properties that match the values in said xml file:

```
public class LogOnUser
{
    #region NestedTypes
    public class Rights
    {
        public bool CanCreateProducts { get; set; }
        public bool CanEditProducts { get; set; }
        public bool CanDeleteProducts { get; set; }
        public bool CanCreateLogIns { get; set; }
        public bool CanDeleteLogIns { get; set; }

        public bool CanBeDeleted { get; set; }
        public bool HasDebugRights { get; set; }
    };
    #endregion

    #region Members
    string _UserName;
    string _Password;
    bool _LoggedIn;
    Rights _UserRights;

    #endregion

    #region Construction
    public LogOnUser() { }

    public LogOnUser(string username)
    {
        _UserName = username;
    }

    public LogOnUser(string username, string password, bool cancreateproducts, bool caneditproducts, bool candeleteproducts, bool cancreatelogins, bool candeletelogins)
    {
        _UserName = username;
        _Password = password;

        _UserRights = new Rights();

        _UserRights.CanCreateProducts = cancreateproducts;
        _UserRights.CanEditProducts = caneditproducts;
        _UserRights.CanDeleteProducts = candeleteproducts;
        _UserRights.CanCreateLogIns = cancreatelogins;
        _UserRights.CanDeleteLogIns = candeletelogins;
    }
    #endregion

    #region Properties
    public string Username
    {
        get { return _UserName; }
        set { _UserName = value; }
    }

    public string Password
    {
        get { return _Password; }
        set { _Password = value; }
    }

    public bool LoggedIn
    {
        get { return _LoggedIn; }
        set { _LoggedIn = value; }
    }

    public Rights UserRights
    {
        get { return _UserRights; }
        set { _UserRights = value; }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

I've tried using XDocument to read certain values from the xml file into instances of my LogOnUser class, however I've become a little stuck and after trawling through the documentation on MSDN and not finding what I'm looking for I figured it might be quicker and easier to ask a question on here.

Basically to begin with I've just tried to read the `UserName` field from the XML into the `UserName` property of a `LogOnUser` object. I tried this:

```
var XMLUser = XElement.Load(LogOnUserXMLFilePath);

foreach(XElement e in XMLUser.DescendantsAndSelf())
{
    var user = new Model.LogOnUsers.LogOnUser(e.Name.ToString());
}
```

however this sets the `UserName` to "LogOnUsersInfo" so obviously I need to go deeper into the xml but I don't know how.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a starter, you can do as follow :

```
foreach(XElement e in XMLUser.Descendants("LogOnUser"))
{
    var user = new Model.LogOnUsers.LogOnUser((string)e.Attribute("UserName"));
}
```

Basically, you can use `Descendants()` to go down the XML tree an arbitrary level deep, and use `Attribute()` to access XML attribute.

Then *rights* information can be obtained as follow, for example :

```
var cancreateproducts = (bool)e.Element("Rights")
                               .Element("CanCreateProducts")
                               .Attribute("value");
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot! How would I then search for different users? Obviously now I only have 2 but it could be considerably more. Would I have to either search the users for say, their usernames for example? Or would it be easier to change each users element name, so rather than them all having `LogOnUser` as the opening tag, they each have a different one?

Comment: The former is the more common approach, if I understand you correctly. Using different tag name for XML elements that carry the same type of information i.e users would make the XML very awkward

Comment: Finding certain user should be as easy as adding `Where()`, right? `XMLUser.Descendants("LogOnUser").Where(o => (string)o.Attribute("UserName") == "User2")`

Comment: Thanks again, exactly what I was after!

Answer (score 1):

You can do an XPath search. You can get all the user info.

```
var nodes = doc.SelectNodes("//LogOnUser");
foreach(var node in nodes)
{
    var username = node.Attributes["Username"];
}
```